# 2012 R2 Mirrored Disk Replacement

Tags: hard-drive, windows-server-2012, mirroring

My Homeserver is currently running on 2 pretty old 400 GB SATA II HDD drives (Manufactured 2007, running 24/7 ever since - 7 Years of Samsung Quality :P). 2 Volumes are created, and a Mirror has been established, using the Diskmanagement. I was not able to mirror the System-reserved volume, which leads to the following result:

[image: Mirrored Volumes]

Click for larger view: http://abload.de/img/mirror7rkt1.png

Now, i want to replace **both** the Disk with SSDs, to improve performance for all the virtual machines located on "D:" while keeping redundancy to ensure availabilty.

1.) I know, that I can remove a mirror and reestablish a mirror on a "new" Disk. But how should I proceed with the system-reserved 100MB-Partition that cannot be mirrored?

2.) In General: Is replacing both disks possible, using the following Steps?

- Remove Mirrors on Disk 4
- Replace Disk 4
- Establish Mirrors on "new Disk 4"
- Remove Mirrors on Disk 3
- Replace Disk 3
- Establish Mirrors on "new Disk 3"

(that's how I think it should *theoretically* work - never tried it before)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since I could not find any information on this, and don't receive any response in other forums as well, I decided to go with *Trial and error*. - In the worst case I would have lost my VMs, but no data, since the storage pool could be included in the new VMs as well.

Heres the way, how I did it:

- I removed the mirror on the two HDDs, which worked perfect in *this* case.
- I replaced one Harddisk with one of the new SSDs and started the system again. (The one remaining harddisk was the one including the System-reserved Space)
- I used the Disk Management to create mirros for the System-Reserved Disk as well as for the C-drive (so we now have a mirror between one of the old hdds and one of the new ssds):

[image]

- Resyncing the drive to the new SSD (Disk 3) took some time, since the source is the hdd (Disk 4).
- After Resyncing the drive I created a new partition on the SSD and moved all VMs to that one using Hyper-V Migration Manager. (could not resync, since the new disk is smaller and the second partition wouldn't fit)
- After this step, I tried to break the Mirror again, to replace the remaining harddisk with the second SSD.
- **But this time, it failed - I dunno way, but i was not able to remove the Mirror within Disk-Management**.
- So I decided to simply detach the HDD in a physical way *simulating* a brokem mirror.
- After a reboot ofc. the mirror was reported broken (disk 4 is now the first ssd and disk3 the second new ssd):

[image]

- So all i had to do was:

  - Remove the mirror from the first SSD again.
  - Create a mirror on the second SSD again.

[image]

(Note: I resized the harddisks before doing that, which leads to the fact that the Virtualization-Drive on the first disk is now splitted into two, cause windows cannot move the "startpoint" of the partition - so the *end* of the partition is now *physically* ahead the start. This has no Impact on the mirror or the way the disk behaves.):

[image]

**Using this approach I successfully migrated my Mirrored-hdd-server to a mirrored-ssd-server without haveing to reinstall or reconfigure anything.**

Maybe this helps somebody, having the same question.

---

**Update:**

When cloning the system-reserved partition, you are ofc. cloning the Boot-Order.

Meaning, afterwards the system will not be able to access the primary plex anymore (cause its gone).

You can manually choose the secondary plex during startup, and then use `msconfig.msc` to remove the no longer existing primary plex.

The new drives are named `secondary` - and `secondary secondary` - but who cares about names?

[image]

Comment: Fun-Fact: I tried to do the same on my win 10 PC, but there it didn't work. The Mirrored drive did not contain proper boot-records, so no matter what, after removing the primary-disk, the system was not able to boot anymore...

Answer (score 1):

Old stuff, but want to help too. I´ve been working with these dynamic windows server disks a while.
To make it easier (to not break it all), before changing HDD´s (1TB) to SSD´s (960GB), using the procedure you posted, check the size of HDDs (and partitions). 
 It need to be less than the size of new SSDs. 
Resize partitions and sync between HDDs and SSDs, changing it like you did, but paying attention in partition and disk sizes.
Regards

Comment: Welcome to Super User. You say, *"It need to be less than the size of new SSDs."* What is the "it" you're referring to? The HDD? Partition? Also, your answer feels a bit incomplete. Please consider making an [edit] to make it more complete as far as all the steps that should be done.